# Simple Injector - RegisterCollection and RegisterDecorator using Composite pattern and interface inheritance

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

How can I register types as `IPollingService<TContext>` so that they'll be decorated via `container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IPollingService<>), typeof(ContextAwarePollingServiceDecorator<>))`, but also register them as a collection of `IPollingService` so that they'll be injected into the constructor of `CompositePollingService` via `container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IPollingService), types)`?

I have the following interfaces:

```
public interface IPollingService { Task Poll(); }
public interface IPollingService<TContext> : IPollingService
    where TContext : CustomContext { TContext Context { get; } }
```

and a Composite-pattern implementation of IPollingService:

```
class CompositePollingService : IPollingService
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IPollingService> _pollingServices;

    public CompositePollingService(IEnumerable<IPollingService> pollingServices) => 
        _pollingServices = pollingServices;

    public async Task Poll() => 
        await Task.WhenAll(_pollingServices.Select(s => s.Poll()));
}
```

All my other implementations of `IPollingService` actually implement `IPollingService<TContext>` but I'm passing them into the `CompositePollingService` constructor as `IEnumerable<IPollingService>` because there will be a mix of `IPollingService<TContext>`, and the `CompositeService` only needs to know about `IPollingService.Poll()`.

I add the types to a list conditionally based on configuration, and use the list to register the collection for the constructor of the `CompositePollingService`:

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
if (// config says to use TEST Context)
   types.Add(typeof(PollingService<TestContext>)); // impl. of IPollingService<TContext>
if (// config says to use LIVE Context)
   types.Add(typeof(PollingService<LiveContext>)); // impl. of IPollingService<TContext>

container.RegisterCollection(typeof(IPollingService), types);
```

I have a decorator for `IPollingService<TContext>`:

```
class ContextAwarePollingServiceDecorator<TContext>
    : IPollingService<TContext> where TContext: CustomContext
{
    private readonly IPollingService<TContext> _decoratee;

    public ContextAwarePollingServiceDecorator(IPollingService<TContext> decoratee) 
        => _decoratee = decoratee;

    public async Task Poll() {
        // decoration here...
        await _decoratee.Poll(cancellationToken);
    }

    public TContext Context => _decoratee.Context;
}
```

However, my decorator is not applied to my `IPollingService<TContext>` implementations, when I register it like this:

```
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IPollingService<>),
    typeof(ContextAwarePollingServiceDecorator<>));
```

How can I register types as `IPollingService<TContext>` but also register them as a collection of `IPollingService` so that they'll be injected into my `CompositePollingService` implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the following code:

```cs
var ls = Lifestyle.Transient;

// Create a collection of InstanceProducer instances for IPollingService<T> registrations
var producers = new InstanceProducer[]
{
   ls.CreateProducer<IPollingService<TestContext>, PollingService<TestContext>>(container),
   ls.CreateProducer<IPollingService<LiveContext>, PollingService<LiveContext>>(container),
};

// Register a decorator that wraps around all IPollingService<T> instances
container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(IPollingService<>),
    typeof(ContextAwarePollingServiceDecorator<>));

// Register the IEnumerable<IPollingService> that contains all IPollingService<T> instances
container.RegisterInstance(producers.Select(p => (IPollingService)p.GetInstance()));

// Register the composite
container.Register<IPollingService, CompositePollingService>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Comment: Thank you - that worked! (of course it did) Other than the API reference, I don't see much in the docs about the reason for using LifeStyle.CreateProducer - is this considered an edge case (read: code smell) with what I'm trying to accomplish? Also, is it a general good practice to make the Composite impl. a Singleton lifestyle? I wasn't specifying that before.

Comment: I don't consider this a code smell, but this is quite an edge case. A design without two interfaces would make it much easier to register, but I'm unsure whether such change would make sense to your application.